# Динамическое обновление контента при скролинге

Tags: javascript, ajax

Хелп! Третий день как не могу решить задачу, есть код, рандомно выводит содержимое из фаила test.php в диве id="test"

```js
var a, r, p;
a = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
r = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);
p = new XMLHttpRequest();
    p.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        l = ( a[r] );
        $("#test").html(myObj[l]);
        }
    };
p.open("GET", "test.php", true);
p.send();
```

Задача: Как обновить содержимое дива id="test" в тот момент как только он скролом в низ документа, вышел из видимой зоне. 
Какие идеи?

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` + jQuery селекторы? сильно. Сегодня уже подобный вопрос задавали (каждую неделю задают): если(высота скролла + выслота окна >= позиция контейнера + высота контейнера) запрос и обновление контента

Comment: **Спасибо** но вопрос остался в силе...

Comment: Главный инструмент любого разработчика - google, я вам дал практически поисковые запросы, попробуйте решить задачу сами для начала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил задачу, не идеал... но работает. Спасибо MedvedevDev за направление.
Само решение:

```js
var a, r, p;
a = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
r = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);
p = new XMLHttpRequest();
     p.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        l = ( a[r] );
        $("#test").html(myObj[l]);
        }
    };
var elmt = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
var pageBottom = elmt[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom + window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > pageBottom) {
p.open("GET", "test.php", true);
p.send();
}
};
```